# error: the option `Z` is only accepted on the nightly compiler

Tags: bash, rust

I am working through the [Stanford Operating Systems Course cs140e](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs140e/). In one of the problems, there is a bash file named test.sh that checks if the Rust programs compile correctly. The test script accepts a -v flag. With -v, the script will emit the error output from the Rust compiler for each failure.

When I run `./test.sh -v` I get this message:

```
error: the option `Z` is only accepted on the nightly compiler
```

Comment: What’s in test.sh? Did you install Rust based off instructions given by the course?

Comment: This question seems to be lacking an actual... *question*. What do you want to know? Do you think the compiler is lying to you? Have you tried installing a nightly toolchain?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Rust has multiple compilers and nightly contains some of the more experimental features. I was able to upgrade from stable Rust to nightly following the advice on the [Rust-Lang-Nursery GitHub Page](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustup.rs#working-with-nightly-rust):

> Install nightly toolchain:
>
> ```
> $ rustup install nightly
> ```
>
> Switch to nightly toolchain as default toolchain:
>
> ```
> $ rustup default nightly
> ```

Comment: I have already done this, but I'm getting the same error while I'm trying to run `cargo`. I have also checked that the current active env is the nightly one but I'm getting the same error, any idea on this?

Comment: Same error. Check your `rust-toolchain` file in your project. Maybe its overriding with an earlier version. I couldn't fix my error yet though...